# Servlet Execution on Link Click

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have page where you have drop-down-box and textarea.
Drop down box is populated with values got from DB.
I know how to do it using scriplets but I want to use strictly servlet solution.
Problem is I know how to use them when for example you click on some bottom in form etc.
But where I have a menu with a link I have no idea what to do.
Is that GET request?
 My link is just 
`http://localhost:8080/TestPage/functionNamesRegister.jsp` 
and from there I jump straight into page with that form.
Should I add annotation `@WebServlet("functionNamesRegister")`
 and then create a servlet with that name?
That is code from menu `<li><a href='functionNamesRegister.jsp' class='daddy'>Register FM Function Names</a></li>`

I am quite new to the servlets I know how to execute them when I have something like:
`<form name='myForm' action='componentRegisterServlet' method='post' onSubmit='return validateCrForm()'>`

I would really appreciate any help from you guys.

Comment: you need to get data for dropdown when your jsp file is loaded in browser without using scriptlet ?

Comment: yes that what I want to do

Comment: See my answer below. May that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Implement just like below example

web.xml

<servlet>
    <description>All XML Functions</description>
    <display-name>XMLTestServlets</display-name>
    <servlet-name>XMLTestServlets</servlet-name> <servlet-class>com.test.testProjects.XMLTestServlets</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XMLTestServlets</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/XMLTestServlets</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



in JSP:

<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/XMLTestServlets">Link Name</a>

just try this...
```

Comment: Testing it I give you a shout how it turned out

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right then you want to execute a Servlet by clicking a link do the following steps :

1. In the web.xml define the configuration of the servlet. If you do this then dont use `WebServlet` annotation.

   `<servlet>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>packagename.className</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/yourUrl</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`
2. In the `jsp` have a link

`<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourUrl">Link Name</a>`

or

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/yourUrl">Link Name</a>
```

Comment: Eclipse is doing that for me isnt? I have mapping for all servlets
I just want to preload some data from DB and print it out on screen when you click that link. But I dont want to have a link like:
`printdb?action=print` just `printdb.jsp` or something similar

Comment: then what you can do is make the servlet to connect to database and retrieve the data and store the data in some Collection object and set it to response and pass it to the jsp retrieve the collection from the request and print it

Comment: I know that but I want to do that automatically when someone click that link

Comment: yep man it will do automatically only from servlet sendRedirect to the jsp

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Servlet` instead of calling directly JSP page.
Write code in servlet to load data for dropdown from Database and set that data in to request attribute and forward your request to JSP page.

Sample example is below for your servlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{  

    String input = "Send this value to JSP";
    request.setAttribute("servlet_value",input);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

In above code pass your value in request attribute by using function `request.setAttribute()` . You can passed any object in it. After that forward your request to JSP page using [RequestDispatcher](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) and [RequestDispatcher.forward()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) function.
It will redirect to your JSP page given in argument. On JSP side you need to read this attribute by using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) or using EL ([Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)).

Sample JSP Code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>JSP Demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   The values from the servlet (ServletValues) is,
   <br>
   <br>
      ${servlet_value}
      <!-- servlet_value is set in the ServletValues servlet. -->
 </body>
</html>
```

You can read your data from database in servlet store in List or Map, passed this using setAttribute`, read your Map or List using`JSTL`.